# Pixel perfect (firebug addon) alternative

Tags: firefox-addon, firebug, pixel-perfect

I've been using [pixel perfect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/) for quite a long time, and grown to love it (despite it's annoyances). Now, when pp is no longer compatibile with fx 6, I'm looking for a tool to replace it.

I found [x-precise](http://codecanyon.net/item/xprecise/full_screen_preview/78685) and am one step from buying it, but I don't quite like the necessity to include something in source page.

I know that I can do it myself, maybe not as good as xprecise or pp, but I just don't have time right now.

I'm curious to know what do you use? Or do you stick to old fx, just to use pixel-prefect?

Comment: It doesn't look like this add-on is really incompatible with Firefox 6, maybe try [Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) to enable it?

Comment: It seems to be the simplest solution. Although the rest is working too. Thanks.

Comment: I have continual issues with Pixel Perfect - FF6-9 freezes frequently, or the PP tab freezes (unable to go to html/css/etc. tabs) - So now I use PerfectPixel on Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "Compatibility Reporter" seems to work for me so far. The only issue I recognized is a needed reload of the page, to see recently added overlays in the pixel-perfect list.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working for 3 years as a developer and created my own script for pixel perfect mode. http://jek-fdrv.16mb.com/pixp/

Comment: +1 - it works, unlike recent forks of PixelPerfect on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, try PerfectPixel
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi

Answer (score 2):

I haven't managed to add a layer in PixelPerfect under any of last Firefox ..27.x.x builds - checkbox is locked. I tried PP versions older than 1.8 it didn't help. I tried to find a decent alternative and failed. Eventually I simply wrote a bookmarklet that provides a similar service http://dsheiko.github.io/pixel-perfect-bookmarklet/.

Answer (score 2):

Pixel Perfect 2 for Firefox native developer tools is available:
https://github.com/firebug/pixel-perfect/wiki

Honza

Answer (score 1):

Just change **line 15** in **install.rfd** file to

```
<em:maxVersion>10.0.*</em:maxVersion>
```

Also there are little issue with left position. To fix it change file **panelAction.js** at **line 108** to

```
this.setPrefValue("pixelPerfect.lastXPos", this.findPixelPerfectXPos(overlayDivId) + 1);
```

at **line 355** to

```
xPos += 1;this.updatePanelDisplayOfXAndY(xPos, yPos);
```

After adding new overlay just refresh page or reopen firebug